# Координата дочернего объекта Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, transform

Ребят, привет всем. Подскажите, правильно ли я обращаюсь для того, чтобы получить координату дочернего объекта, который сам является дочерним?

```
nailDeskInst.GetComponentInChildren<Transform>().GetChild(1).gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Transform>().GetChild(0).gameObject.transform.position.x
```

Comment: В смысле, правильно или неправильно? Ваш вопрос напоминает этот [мем](http://img1.joyreactor.cc/pics/post/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-183931.jpeg). Если ваш код работает, то в чем проблема, а если нет, то нужно указать точную ошибку...

Answer (score 1):

Для объекта к которому привязан скрипт можно просто писать `transform`.
Для остальных `yourObject.transform`.

`GetChild()` сам по себе возвращает `Transform`!

Схему с `GetComponentInChildren` вообще не понял... запутанно.

```
nailDeskInst.transform.GetChild(1).GetChild(0).position.x;
```

Но вообще в этом случае `GetChild(index)` зло и костыли! Нужно ссылку на объект иметь!